# Javascript: use an icon to control the visibility of a section of content

Tags: javascript

I want to use a few icon images to control the visibility of the section corresponding to the icon images, but I keep getting error messages in the console. I wrote a for loop that goes through the icon images that has the class of "LED", and an if statement that toggle the visibility of the section.

HTML:

```
<ul>
            <li>
                <img src="images/LED.png"  class="LED"/>
                <h2><span>&lt;&nbsp;</span>Education<span>&nbsp;&gt;</span></h2>
                <ul class="content">

                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <img src="images/LED.png" class="LED"/>
                <h2><span>&lt;&nbsp;</span>Experience<span>&nbsp;&gt;</span></h2>
                <ul class="content">

                </ul>
            </li>

             <li>
                <img src="images/LED.png" class="LED"/>
                <h2><span>&lt;&nbsp;</span>Skills<span>&nbsp;&gt;</span></h2>
                <ul class="content">

                </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var LEDs = document.querySelectorAll('.LED'), i;
var contents= document.querySelectorAll('.content'), i;


for(var i = 0; i<LEDs.length; i++){
    var isVisible[i] = true;
    LEDs[i].addEventListener('click', 
        function (evt){

            if(isVisible[i]){
                contents[i].classList.add('hidden');
                isVisible[i] = false;

            }else{
                contents[i].classList.remove('hidden');
                isVisible[i] = true;
            }

    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some syntax error

```
var isVisible[i] = true;
```

nope, to declaring an array you cannot do this. Furthermore, I think you want only one `isVisible` array instance across the loop. So I think you should do this

```
var isVisible = [];
for(var i = 0; i<LEDs.length; i++){
    isVisible[i] = true;
```

Next is a common trap about closure. You create a closure as event listener on click. However, the `i` captured by the closure is bound to the context of the for-loop. In other words, `i` in the closure will change as `i` changes in the loop. So you need to define other factory function to limit the context of `i`, or to fix it.

```
function createListener(i) {
    return function (evt){

            if(isVisible[i]){
                contents[i].classList.add('hidden');
                isVisible[i] = false;

            }else{
                contents[i].classList.remove('hidden');
                isVisible[i] = true;
            }

    };    
}
```

Here's a working one.
http://jsfiddle.net/vnbwmbL7/

Comment: yep, nice. I missed a closure at first look ) next time I saw it, but you are answered already ) get a Plus )

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you declaration of variable "var isVisible[i] = true;" is wrong.

do first

```
var isVisible = [];
```

then

```
isVisible[i] = true
```

And I think you need define it outside the loop